# Is it possible to connect Spark to Cosmos DB using MongoDB api?

Tags: mongodb, azure, apache-spark, azure-cosmosdb, azure-hdinsight

I'm using HDInsight with Spark. At the moment, I'm able to write and read data directly from Cosmos DB (SQL API) with Spark.
Using:

```
spark.jars.packages     com.microsoft.azure:azure-cosmosdb-spark_2.1.0_2.11:1.0.0
```

I'm unable to find out a way to connect Spark directly to Cosmos DB with MongoDB API. I have tried the above configuration, and also the MongoDB connector for Spark but without success.

```
spark.jars.packages    org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.1.0
```

So, is possible to connect Spark to a Cosmos DB that use MongoDB API?

I get this error:

> ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
>   org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: Document does not contain key
>   cursor
>           at org.bson.BsonDocument.throwIfKeyAbsent(BsonDocument.java:844)
>           at org.bson.BsonDocument.getDocument(BsonDocument.java:135)
>           at com.mongodb.operation.AggregateOperation.createQueryResult(AggregateOperation.java:359)
>           at com.mongodb.operation.AggregateOperation.access$700(AggregateOperation.java:67)
>           at com.mongodb.operation.AggregateOperation$3.apply(AggregateOperation.java:367)
>           at com.mongodb.operation.AggregateOperation$3.apply(AggregateOperation.java:364)
>           at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:216)
>           at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:207)
>           at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:113)
>           at com.mongodb.operation.AggregateOperation$1.call(AggregateOperation.java:257)
>           at com.mongodb.operation.AggregateOperation$1.call(AggregateOperation.java:253)
>           at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:431)
>           at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:404)
>           at com.mongodb.operation.AggregateOperation.execute(AggregateOperation.java:253)
>           at com.mongodb.operation.AggregateOperation.execute(AggregateOperation.java:67)
>           at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:836)
>           at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:823)
>           at com.mongodb.OperationIterable.iterator(OperationIterable.java:47)
>           at com.mongodb.AggregateIterableImpl.iterator(AggregateIterableImpl.java:123)
>           at com.mongodb.spark.rdd.MongoRDD.getCursor(MongoRDD.scala:167)
>           at com.mongodb.spark.rdd.MongoRDD.compute(MongoRDD.scala:142)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
>           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:325)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: It should be possible; could you provide the error you received?  BTW, if you are using HDInsight, you may need to use the mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.1.0 version as HDI 3.6 is currently on Spark 2.1.

Comment: thanks! I fixed the version to 2.1.0, but i get the same error. I added the error in the question...

Comment: Got it - looking at the error, this may be different than what I originally thought.  Could you email me at askcosmosdb@microsoft.com for some account specific questions?  Thanks!